# Rails 3 Model associations with has_many, belongs_to and :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to put together a couple of model associations for a small project I'm working on. I am new to Rails, so this is all a bit confusing to me.

My use case is pretty straight forward. I have a Sporting **League** which *has many* **Divisions**. Each **Division** *has many* **Teams**. Each **Team** *has one* **Captain** and *has many* **Players**.

Now, both Players and Captains are represented by Class User. The only thing that differentiates them is their Role. I am using *CanCan* to manage the Roles.

Now here are my Models and how I have defined the associations:

```
class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :teams
end
```

---

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :divisions
end
```

---

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :division
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :division

  has_one :captain, :class_name => "User"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :captain

  has_many :rosters
  has_many :players, :through => :rosters, :source => :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :rosters
  has_many :teams, :through => :rosters
  belongs_to :team
end
```

---

[And here is my generated Schema file.](https://gist.github.com/7c5c885450fd3c280856)

1. Have I defined my model associations correctly?
2. How do I go about assigning a Player or Captain to a Team when I am creating or editing a team?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The definition seems OK to me. There are other ways of doing it (of course) but this one seems OK.
2. This sort of depends on your UI. The captain should be simple enough - do a `collection_select` and assign it to the `captain` attribute.

Players are a bit more tricky. The usual approach is (as you do) to use `collection_select` with a html array `name` (eg. `team[player_id][]`) and in your case I imagine you have a set number of players for each team so you just display it that many times (if not you can use javascript to clone it for the user).

Comment: I'd be interested to learn about the different ways of defining these models and associations. Because honestly, all this belongs_to and has_many stuff really confuses me.

Comment: You could for example not define the captain as a has_one but rather have that be an attribute of the roster model. But using has_one in this situation seems good.